# Can't set bitmap to image button?

Tags: android, bitmap, sharedpreferences

```
03-04 11:49:54.672: W/dalvikvm(1640): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.speedlink/com.speedlink.topmenu.SPDTeamTop}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at com.speedlink.topmenu.SPDTeamTop.onCreate(SPDTeamTop.java:79)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-04 11:49:54.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1640):     ... 11 more
```

I got this error when retrieve image base64 from shared preference and set to image button. I changed Image Path to bitmap and bitmap to base64tostring to store in shared preference, Image path and base64tostring is activated but set image bitmap to imagebutton has errors... Here is my code.

```
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
 Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, false);
 edit.putString("TeamPhotoSaved", encodeTobase64(resized));
```

This is store in shared preferences.

```
     public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immage = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.d("Image Log:", imageEncoded);
        return imageEncoded;
    }

 public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
     byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
     return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
 }
```

This is bitmap decode and encode...

```
 bitmap=Login.decodeBase64(teamphotoSaved);     
 imgbtn_community.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This is set to image button.

Edit: Top.java

```
 SharedPreferences userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
teamphotoSaved = userDetails.getString("TeamPhotoSaved", "");
bitmap=Login.decodeBase64(teamphotoSaved);
imgbtn_community.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: which is line number `79` in SPDTeamTop.java ?

Comment: It is a class which retrieve image from sharedpreference and set to imagebutton.

Comment: are getting url in the form of string ?

Comment: where are you retrieve the image from SP?

Comment: Yes, url is a string @ Anjali Tripathi .

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta . Sharedpreferences, not bitmap but base64encodetostring.

Comment: then you can lazy image loader..here is a link https://github.com/thest1/LazyList ...

Comment: edit.getString("TeamPhotoSaved", bitmap); have you used this anywhere?

Comment: and where you want to show that image use this imageLoader.DisplayImage(yoururl, R.drawable.ic_stub, imageView);

Comment: @Piyush Gupta edit.getString("TeamPhotoSaved", String)... Sharedpreference can't save bitmap. So, I saved as String...

Comment: I know that but i have asked have you used that one and where?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta, Yes, In SpdTeamTop.java.  teamphotoSaved = userDetails.getString("TeamPhotoSaved", "");bitmap=com.speedlink.login.SPDLogin.decodeBase64(teamphotoSaved);      
 imgbtn_community.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Show your SPDTeamTop.java full class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass context with ***getSharedPreference***. Its not compulsory. So have to just change from. because may be your **context** variable is null.

```
SharedPreferences userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Must be insure that when you have trying to store data in shared prefernce at that time the key and the Mode of shared preference must be same when you retrieve and store data in it.So this will be same when you store data

```
SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: No, It's not. I can't settle the problem.

Comment: have you checked what i have said? Another tell me exactly at which line you got NPE?

Comment: imgbtn_community.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // this line

Comment: check **imgbtn_community** id same in xml file? Have you find ID for it in your java file?

Comment: Yes, I did it.   imgbtn_community=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_community);

Comment: Sorry, I'm late. Your're very good developer. I settled my error. Thank you very much... :)

Comment: Thanks. But how and where is the problem.?

Comment: Oh...happen sometimes. no worry you would be good developer after done a mistake bcos mistake teach us to make good developer.